# When are the unnecessary row versions being removed from the version store

Tags: sql-server, tempdb-version-store

Sorry for my bad English :)

I need a help with understanding version store`s cleaning. I have the following situation.

1. 12:00 Start a select statement under the snapshot isolation level and not commit.
2. 12:01 Start an update statement (update a single row) under the read committed isolation level and commit.
3. 12:02 Start a select statement under the snapshot isolation level and not commit.
4. 12:03 Start an update statement (update a single row) under the read committed isolation level and commit.

Now if we look at the version store such as

```sql
SELECT *
FROM sys.dm_tran_version_store
```

We will see there are 2 rows (one row for each update statement).

Now if we commit the first transactions that starts at 12:00, no row is being removed from the version store (even past a minute).

The question is **WHY???**.

In my opinion one of the rows have to be removed from the version store, because there are no active transactions, that have access to that version.

I tried also to update no 1 row, but 100 rows (Total more then 100 KB) but I have the same situation, the version store is not being removed.

Please help me to understand when the version store is being cleaned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now if we commit the first transactions that starts at 12:00, no row is being removed from the version store (even pass a minute).
>
> The question is WHY ?

Minimal condition for a version row to be garbage collected is **when SQL Server determines, based on the transactional states, that this version is no longer needed.**

Also, referring to my SQL Server internals notes, for management of version store, SQL Server will perform a regular cleanup every minute with a background process to reclaim all the reusable space from the version store.

You can monitor `Version generation rate and version cleanup rate` in `SQLServer:Transactions` perfmon counter to find out rate at which space is acquired and released from version store in KB/Sec.

Check : [Managing TempDB in SQL Server: TempDB Basics (Version Store: Simple Example)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sqlserverstorageengine/managing-tempdb-in-sql-server-tempdb-basics-version-store-simple-example)

Comment: And the second questions is - when does the SQL Server determines, that the version is no longer need? In my case only the transaction started in 12:00 need the version created in the 12:01 because of update. But the transaction started in 12:00 is committed, and the 1 minute is past, but version store has not been cleaned.